# R: Loop over several column to compare variables

Tags: r

I would like to loop over several columns to compare those variables within a data frame.

For example:

```
df1
| col1     | col2  | col3  |
| -------- | ------|-------|
| First    | PwC   | PwC   |
| Second   | BCG   | BCG   |
| Third    | web   | txt   |
```

Looking at that example I would like to loop over col2 and col3.

If df1[1,2] == df1[1,3], then write 0 in a new col4, else write 1 in the col4.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df1$col4<-ifelse(df1$col2 == df1$col3, 1, 0)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need a loop for this.  Just create a logical vector and coerce it to binary (`as.integer`)

```
df1$col4 <- as.integer(df1$col2 != df1$col3)
```